# listview in relativelayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am trying to have two panels on my screen, in which on top I have listview that resides in relativelayout. I put listview inside relativelayout coz I need to have some border color or something, just to separate each panel.

The problem is the size of relative layout is bigger then listview and there is extra color if there is no element in listview to fill relative layout. 
I stuck in it, how should I balance both panels. 
Thanks

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_panel">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/top_panel"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#D3D3D3"
android:layout_above="@+id/chart">
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"> </FrameLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make `layout_width` and `layout_height` `match_parent`.

Comment: use `android:layout_weight = "1"`

Comment: @AndresCardenasPardo **weights** only work in `LinearLayouts`, not in `RelativeLayouts`.

Comment: humm, true, then the solution is use LinearLayouts :D

Comment: maybe not. RelativeLayouts are powerful beasts.

Comment: Do you **really need** all this **layout nesting**?

Comment: I have added layout nesting to obtain bit change between them, may be I am wrong, if you optimised way to do it?

Comment: Unnecessary layouts should be removed (i.e.: the RelativeLayout containing the ListView). Also the usage of "anticipated reference" isn't good for performances. I'd put the FrameLayout before and then the ListView **below** it (and having the ListView match the available space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My optimized solution would be:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/top_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/chart"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your layout like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/main_panel">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/top_panel"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#D3D3D3"
android:layout_above="@+id/chart">
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"> </FrameLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

by setting `RelativeLayout` height to `wrap_content` when list is empty, the whole view is smaller and if you don't want this, then you should change `ListView` height to `match_parent`

Comment: Do you **really need** all this **layout nesting**?

Comment: I just wanted to use his/her own layout and just changed one attribute and I think one of `RelativeLayout`s are useless.

Comment: Yes it is. Also the usage of "anticipated reference" isn't good for performances. I'd put the FrameLayout before and then the ListView **below** it (and having the ListView match the available space).